# Use Animations with navigations in WearOS

Tags: kotlin, animation, wear-os, navcontroller

I have a `swipeDissmissableNavController` with a `SwipeDismissableNavHost` and I want to add in animations when entering a new page. I tried it the following way:

```
    val navController = rememberSwipeDismissableNavController()
    SwipeDismissableNavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = "startDestination",
    enterTransition = //enterTransition here
    ){
   // composables here
}
```

But it does not take any enterTransition parameters ore similar.

Any ideas?